# XML Insert attribute

Tags: xml, sql-server-2008, sqlxml

When I update an xml column:

```
SET XmlDocumentData.modify('insert attribute User {sql:variable("@User")} 
    as last into (/Configuration/Process/Tasks)[1] ')
```

I am getting an error:

> Msg 6905, Level 16, State 3, Line 27
>   XML Validation: Attribute 'User' is
>   not permitted in this context.
>   Location: //@*:User

What is a way to add new attributes in every task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess that the column XmlDocumentData is bound to a Schema Collection and that the `User` attribute is not allowed in the `Tasks` node. Keep in mind that XML is case sensitive.